# Comparing Multiple Strings In Perl

Tags: perl

I have my code like this:

```
if ( $var eq "str1" || $var eq "str2" || $var eq "str3" )
{
...
}
```

Is there anyways to optimize this.
I want something like:

```
if ( $var eq ["str1" || "str2" || "str3"] ) {...}
```

Comment: If by "optimize" you mean "make it go faster", the first version is optimal (if you order the strings so that the most likely one is in front).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on the contents of the strings, a regex is quite convenient:

```
if ($var =~ /^(str1|str2|str3)$/) { … }
```

Failing that, you can grep over a list:

```
if (grep { $var eq $_ } qw{str1 str2 str3}) { … }
```

Comment: thank you so much.. The first expression worked but with the brackets removed: if ($var =~ /^str1|str2|str3$/)

Comment: @user988967, No, it doesn't. Without the parens, it will match `str1A`, `Astr2A` and `Astr3`.

Comment: @ikegami, yes you are correct. thanks.. One more query. I'm using "use strict" at the top of my code. so would you advise me to use "?:"

Comment: @user988967, I don't understand the question. `use strict;` has nothing to do with regex, and I already explained why `(?:...)` is needed. `(...)` would work too, but it's function is to capture, which is needless work here.

Comment: @ikegami: I don't agree with that edit. Adding `?:` is needless complexity for the programmer, and is thus a case of premature optimisation. I only use `?:` to avoid confusion with intended captures.

Answer (score 14):

In Perl 5.10 or better:

```
if ($var ~~ [qw( str1 str2 str3 )]) { ...}
```

The `~~` operator does a [smart match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) between its arguments.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: ***"The smartmatch operator is experimental and its behavior is subject to change."*** I recommend you avoid it

Comment: @Borodin: I generally avoid Perl, but +1 for the heads-up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `List::MoreUtils qw{any}`

   ```
   use List::MoreUtils qw{any};

   if ( any { $var eq $_ } 'str1', 'str2', 'str3' ) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   This might be faster than using `grep` because `List::MoreUtils::any` finishes early when it finds a match whereas `grep` might build a complete list of matches. I say 'might' because Perl could conceivably optimise `if (grep ...`. It might not. But `List::MoreUtils::any` does finish early, and it's more descriptive than the `if (grep ...` idiom.
2. Make a hash that has keys of all the strings you want to match

   ```
   my %matcher;

   @matcher{qw{str1 str2 str3}} = ();

   if ( exists $matcher{$var} ) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   This has the disadvantage of a set-up time and the cost of the memory used for the hash, but the advantage is that the match time is more like O(log N). So if you have lots of different values of `$var` that you want to test then it could be faster overall.
3. Make a regex that matches all of your strings

   ```
   if ( $var =~ m/^str[123]$/so ) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   OK, so this is fine if your strings are literally `qw{str1 str2 str3}`, but what if it is a list of arbitrary strings?

   You could use [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aAssemble) to fuse together a list of regexps into a single optimised regexp.

Comment: [Regexp::Assemble](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Assemble) is not needed on newer Perls, since regexps now have [Trie optimization](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Trie-optimisation-of-literal-string-alternations).

Answer (score 1):

For a list of fixed strings, convert your list to a hash. This is especially useful if you are going to check against your list several times, and if your list gets larger.

```
%on_my_list = map {; $_ => 1 } 'str1', 'str2', 'str3', ...;

if ($on_my_list{$var}) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm semi-joking, but this will do it:

```
use Quantum::Superpositions;

if ($x == any($a, $b, $c)) { ...  }
```

See also this [Perl Monks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=607459)